# Redirect from Global.asax.cs continues on to original route

Tags: c#, redirect, model-view-controller, routes, global-asax

I am trying to redirect to a specified page from the global.asax.cs page. I know the redirect works because the debugger hits a breakpoint in the view. The problem is the app proceeds to the original route after first going to the new route. Am I missing a command to tell it to stop at the new route? 
Here is the code as it exists inside the Session_Start method:

```
Employee emp = Work.GetEmployee(userName);
if (emp.Id == 0)
{
    Response.Clear();
    RouteData rd = new RouteData();
    rd.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
    rd.Values.Add("action", "UserNotFound");

    IController errorController = new ErrorController();
    errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(
        new HttpContextWrapper(Context), rd));
}
else
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"] = emp;
    AppAdminWork.SetUsersCurrentApplications(emp);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Suggest doing this in an action filter -- then you are not fighting the framework.

Comment: Good suggestion, I'm already heading in that direction.

Comment: I ended up refactoring my code to use an action filter, applying it at the controller level to all controllers except the ErrorController. Works like a charm. Thanks @dbugger !!!

Comment: you're welcome -- did you add a base controller to save some copy and pasting?